# Android SearchView casting exception

Tags: android, searchview

Here is my problem

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: a2msoft.app_one, PID: 9608
>                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
>                                                        at a2msoft.app_one.activiy.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:202)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3142)

```
import a2msoft.app_one.AppConfig;
import a2msoft.app_one.AppController;
import a2msoft.app_one.adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import a2msoft.app_one.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    SearchView searchView ;
    //private static final String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Recipie> movieList = new ArrayList<Recipie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
......
....



@Override
    public  boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search); // error comes up here
          searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
         @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            return  false;

        }
        @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String change)
        {
            return false;
        }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item

        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />

</menu>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="a2msoft.app_one">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activiy.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activiy.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activiy.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activiy.ItemActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"

            android:parentActivityName=".activiy.MainActivity"


            />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activiy.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help

Comment: I can't see where this is coming from   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

instead of this

```
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search); // error comes up here
```

**Sample code**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
     @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    {
        return  false;

    }
    @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String change)
    {
        return false;
    }
    });
    return true;

}
```

Comment: awesome... this worked ..actually I had tried this earlier but didnt work.. anyways , thank you much Nilu

Comment: @user1130456 happy to help you enjoy codding